# Why are sometimes my Div Class Attributes not being applied from my css?

Tags: html, css, class

While my CSS works sometimes the specific properties are not executed.  This can been seen in the Chrome Console where they have a line thru them, indicating that they are not being applied.  I thought the more specific DIV classes would have a higher execution priority than the general Div.

In particular, I'm trying to set the padding for p.note   I can set a separate text size for <p.note> smaller than p but not the margins or padding.  I call it in my HTML using:

```
    <p class="note">
```

As apparently <p.note> does not work.

Following is the relevant CSS fragment and some pix showing that it's not applied.  A lot of what I'm trying to apply in the <p.note> isn't be applied due to priorities.  How can I fix this?

```
* {
margin: 1rem;
padding: 1rem;
/*  outline: solid black 2px;  */
box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* define all paragraph font for main pg */
p {
color: black;
text-align: left;
font-family: palatino;
font-size: 1.1rem;
background-color: rgba(238,238,238,0.7); /* off-white translucent  */
/* margin: 4 prop is Top R Bott L no , but spaces*/
margin: 1.7rem;
padding: 1rem;
outline: solid black 1px;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

p.note { background-color: rgba(88,190,238,0.23); /* purple translucent */
font-size: .8rem;
/* margin: 4 prop is Top R Bott L no , but spaces*/
margin: 1.7rem;
padding: .25,1,.25,1rem;
outline: solid black 1px;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

p::first-letter {
font-family: Georgia, serif;
/* font-family:  Luminary, fantasy; not allowed by Chrome */
font-size:2.0rem; color: #2f2f2f;
}
```

Any suggestions from CSS experts would be appreciated as I'm very slowly trying to learn CSS bit by bit.

[image: Classes voided out by Chrome]

Comment: Your padding attribute is wrong, remove the commas.

Comment: Voting to close because of a typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an error in your css syntax for:

padding: .25,1,.25,1rem;

in

```
p.note { background-color: rgba(88,190,238,0.23); /* purple translucent */
font-size: .8rem;
/* margin: 4 prop is Top R Bott L no , but spaces*/
margin: 1.7rem;
padding: .25,1,.25,1rem;
outline: solid black 1px;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

use the proper syntax and the style will be applied.
ex:

**padding: .25rem 1rem .25rem 1rem**

you can use this equivalent rule too:

**padding: .25rem 1rem**

remove the comma and add the unit for each value.

Comment: Thanks so much.  I picked up this bad habit somewhere of using this format.  Perhaps it's an old and obsolete format. It now works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

The "padding: .25,1,.25,1rem;" is wrong

it should be padding: .25rem 1rem

dont use commas and make sure you put a unit at the end of each value

Comment: No problem! Glad it fixed your issue